# Why is a validation exception thrown on a field which is not being updated?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, validation, entity-framework-6

I am using EF 6.0.2 and trying to update only the `Status` field of an entity.

```
var drama = new Drama { Id = id };
using (var ctx = new DataContext()) {
  ctx.Dramas.Attach(drama);
  drama.Status = state;
  ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

This throws a ValidationException: **The `ClassName` field is required.**

The entity already exists, and is valid (including having a `ClassName`). `Id` is the entity key.

What's going on here to cause the exception to be thrown?

Comment: What does your DataContext look like?

Comment: It's got probably about 20 entities. Not sure what you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're saying there already is an entity with the given `Id` in the database and you'd only like to change its `Status` value?

That's not what you're doing in your code. You have created a new entity with the given `Id` and set only its `Status` value. That's why it's throwing a `ValidationException`: `ClassName` field is empty unless you're setting it in `Drama` constructor.

To modify an existing entity you should first retrieve it from the database, then modify it and save the changes:

```
using (var ctx = new DataContext()) {
    var drama = ctx.Dramas.Single(d => d.Id == id);
    drama.Status = state;
    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

EDIT:

If you want to simulate a scenario of editing a detached entity, you still need its values to be valid. Try fulfilling all the validation requirements before attaching the entity (i.e. fill in the `ClassName`), then `Attach` it, update `Status` and `SaveChanges`:

```
var drama = new Drama { Id = id, ClassName = "Dummy" };
using (var ctx = new DataContext()) {
    ctx.Dramas.Attach(drama);
    drama.Status = state;
    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: But that results in two separate database operations, and I'm doing this in a loop in my actual code (should have said this before). To modify just one or two properties without retrieving the whole entity first, I have always been able to use the Attach method. But not sure why it's failing now.

Comment: I agree with @Damir, and thats how we do edits in EF

Comment: Say you have a million records (perhaps some with very large TEXT or BLOB fields) and you want to flip a boolean field in each one from True to False. Loading them all fully into memory would be very wasteful.

Comment: @James If you want to simulate a scenario of editing a detached entity, you still need its values to be valid. Try fulfilling all the validation requirements before attaching the entity (i.e. fill in the `ClassName`), then `Attach` it, update `Status` and `SaveChanges`.

Comment: @Damir That works! Makes sense now that you say it... I assumed it was the database complaining rather than EF. Please add this as an answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 0):

When you do edits in EF, you should get the entire record that you are editing and then put the fields whatever you want to update.

```
using (var ctx = new DataContext()) {
  drama = ctx.Dramas.Where(O => O.Id = id);
  drama.Status = state;
  ctx.Dramas.Attach(drama);
  ctx.SaveChanges();
```

}

Hope this helps